What is the minimum level of DBCC CHECKDB needed to check full-text indexes?
I have a database containing an unreasonably large full-text index. DBCC CHECKDB WITH PHYSICAL_ONLY takes about 25 minutes on this database, but DBCC CHECKDB WITH DATA_PURITY, EXTENDED_LOGICAL_CHECKS takes about 2 hours longer. This suggests to me that PHYSICAL_ONLY skips full-text indexes.
Am I correct? What parameters need to be passed to CHECKDB to have it check full-text indexes?

Continued experiments suggest that the performance of DBCC CHECKDB WITH DATA_PURITY, EXTENDED_LOGICAL_CHECKS and DBCC CHECKDB is indistinguishable on databases with massive full-text indexes. It appears that only DBCC CHECKDB WITH PHYSICAL_ONLY skips full-text indexes.
